# How to parse user-uploaded pdf/doc file (through a Flask framework) using textract library without saving file locally?

Tags: python, parsing, pdf, flask, text-extraction

I am trying to modify this resume parser https://github.com/bjherger/ResumeParser by creating an API for it. I have used a flask framework to create an API where users can upload pdf/doc files. Here is the code for the flask framework:

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'user_uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf','doc','docx', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 
'gif'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
    return filename[-3:].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():

if request.method == 'POST':

    file = request.files['file']
    print type(file)
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        print "File uploaded successfully. File name is" +file.filename
```

After getting the user upload, I will then use the textract.process() method from the textract library. However, the 'file' object is a werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage object which cannot be parsed by textract.

Is there any way to convert the FileStorage object back into pdf/doc, without saving the file to the server, so that textract can parse it ?

Comment: [PD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28321690/5033247)

Comment: use `file.read()`